# Can malloc_trim() release memory from the middle of the heap?

Tags: linux, memory, operating-system, malloc, glibc

I am confused about the behaviour of malloc_trim as implemented in the glibc.

```
man malloc_trim
[...]
malloc_trim - release free memory from the top of the heap
[...]
This function cannot release free memory located at places other than the top of the heap.
```

When I now look up the source of `malloc_trim()` (in malloc/malloc.c) I see that it calls `mtrim()` which is utilizing `madvise(x, MADV_DONTNEED)` to release memory back to the operating system.

So I wonder if the man-page is wrong or if I misinterpret the source in malloc/malloc.c.

Can `malloc_trim()` release memory from the middle of the heap?

Comment: Isn't it right there in the documentation? `This function cannot release free memory located at places other than the top of the heap.`

Comment: @tangrs The thing is that from looking at the actual implementation I think the documentation is wrong (but I am not quite sure).

Comment: Always listen to the documentation. The documented behaviour of a function will never change but the implementation can. Relying on the function using a specific implementation can mean your program will break with future versions or on different platforms.

Comment: I care about the behaviour of a specific implementation. In my question I said I am talking about the glibc.

Comment: There's nothing preventing the implementation from changing between versions of glibc...

Answer (score 2):

There are two usages of `madvise` with `MADV_DONTNEED` in glibc now: http://code.metager.de/source/search?q=MADV_DONTNEED&path=%2Fgnu%2Fglibc%2Fmalloc%2F&project=gnu

```
 H A D  arena.c 643 __madvise ((char *) h + new_size, diff, MADV_DONTNEED);
 H A D  malloc.c    4535 __madvise (paligned_mem, size & ~psm1, MADV_DONTNEED);
```

There was https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=68631c8eb92ff38d9da1ae34f6aa048539b199cc commit by Ulrich Drepper on 16 Dec 2007 (part of glibc 2.9 and newer):

> - malloc/malloc.c (public_mTRIm): Iterate over all arenas and call
>
> mTRIm for all of them.
>   (mTRIm): Additionally iterate over all free blocks and use madvise
>   to free memory for all those blocks which contain at least one
>   memory page.

`mTRIm` (now [`mtrim`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/malloc/malloc.c#4492)) implementation was changed. Unused parts of chunks, aligned on page size and having size more than page may be marked as `MADV_DONTNEED`:

```
           /* See whether the chunk contains at least one unused page.  */
           char *paligned_mem = (char *) (((uintptr_t) p
                                           + sizeof (struct malloc_chunk)
                                           + psm1) & ~psm1);

           assert ((char *) chunk2mem (p) + 4 * SIZE_SZ <= paligned_mem);
           assert ((char *) p + size > paligned_mem);

           /* This is the size we could potentially free.  */
           size -= paligned_mem - (char *) p;

           if (size > psm1)
               madvise (paligned_mem, size & ~psm1, MADV_DONTNEED);
```

Man page of `malloc_trim` is there: https://github.com/mkerrisk/man-pages/blob/master/man3/malloc_trim.3 and it was committed by kerrisk in 2012: https://github.com/mkerrisk/man-pages/commit/a15b0e60b297e29c825b7417582a33e6ca26bf65

As I can [grep the glibc's git, there are no man pages in the glibc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=malloc_trim), and no commit to malloc_trim manpage to document this patch. The best and the only documentation of glibc malloc is its source code: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c

```
Additional functions:
 malloc_trim(size_t pad);
 609 /*
 610   malloc_trim(size_t pad);
 611 
 612   If possible, gives memory back to the system (via negative
 613   arguments to sbrk) if there is unused memory at the `high' end of
 614   the malloc pool. You can call this after freeing large blocks of
 615   memory to potentially reduce the system-level memory requirements
 616   of a program. However, it cannot guarantee to reduce memory. Under
 617   some allocation patterns, some large free blocks of memory will be
 618   locked between two used chunks, so they cannot be given back to
 619   the system.
 620 
 621   The `pad' argument to malloc_trim represents the amount of free
 622   trailing space to leave untrimmed. If this argument is zero,
 623   only the minimum amount of memory to maintain internal data
 624   structures will be left (one page or less). Non-zero arguments
 625   can be supplied to maintain enough trailing space to service
 626   future expected allocations without having to re-obtain memory
 627   from the system.
 628 
 629   Malloc_trim returns 1 if it actually released any memory, else 0.
 630   On systems that do not support "negative sbrks", it will always
 631   return 0.
 632 */
 633 int      __malloc_trim(size_t);
 634
```

Freeing from the middle of the chunk is not documented as text in malloc/malloc.c (and `malloc_trim` description in commend was not updated in 2007) and not documented in man-pages project. Man page from 2012 may be the first man page of the function, written not by authors of glibc. Info page of glibc only mentions M_TRIM_THRESHOLD of 128 KB:
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Malloc-Tunable-Parameters.html#Malloc-Tunable-Parameters  and don't list malloc_trim function https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Summary-of-Malloc.html#Summary-of-Malloc (and it also don't document memusage/memusagestat/libmemusage.so).

You may ask Drepper and other glibc developers again as you already did in https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2015-02/msg00022.html "malloc_trim() behaviour", but there is still no reply from them. (Only wrong answers from other users like https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2015-05/msg00007.html https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2015-05/msg00008.html)

Or you may test the `malloc_trim` with this simple C program (`test_malloc_trim.c`) and `strace`/`ltrace`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
    int *m1,*m2,*m3,*m4;
    printf("%s\n","Test started");
    m1=(int*)malloc(20000);
    m2=(int*)malloc(40000);
    m3=(int*)malloc(80000);
    m4=(int*)malloc(10000);
    printf("1:%p 2:%p 3:%p 4:%p\n", m1, m2, m3, m4);
    free(m2);
    malloc_trim(0); // 20000, 2000000
    sleep(1);
    free(m1);
    free(m3);
    free(m4);
    // malloc_stats(); malloc_info(0, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

`gcc test_malloc_trim.c -o test_malloc_trim`, `strace ./test_malloc_trim`

```
write(1, "Test started\n", 13Test started
)          = 13
brk(0)                                  = 0xcca000
brk(0xcef000)                           = 0xcef000
write(1, "1:0xcca010 2:0xccee40 3:0xcd8a90"..., 441:0xcca010 2:0xccee40 3:0xcd8a90 4:0xcec320
) = 44
madvise(0xccf000, 36864, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
nanosleep({1, 0}, 0x7ffffafbfff0)       = 0
brk(0xceb000)                           = 0xceb000
```

So, there is `madvise` with `MADV_DONTNEED` for 9 pages after `malloc_trim(0)` call, when there was hole of 40008 bytes in the middle of the heap.

Comment: Kind of typical official position of GNU-like project maintainer on man pages and other documentation: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2531#c4 "Ulrich Drepper 2006-05-01 The man pages are not maintained in glibc.  Tell this to the man page maintainer."

Answer (score 1):

> ... utilizing madvise(x, MADV_DONTNEED) to release memory back to the
>   operating system.

`madvise(x, MADV_DONTNEED)` does not *release* memory. `man madvise`:

> **MADV_DONTNEED**
>                 Do not expect access in the near future.  (For the  time  being,
>                 the  application is finished with the given range, so the kernel
>                 can free resources associated with it.)  Subsequent accesses  of
>                 pages  in  this  range  will  succeed, but will result either in
>                 reloading of the memory contents from the underlying mapped file
>                 (see  **mmap**(2)) or zero-fill-on-demand pages for mappings without
>                 an underlying file.

So, the usage of `madvise(x, MADV_DONTNEED)` does not contradict `man malloc_trim`'s statement:

> This function cannot release free memory located at places other than the top of the heap.

Comment: About madvise(x, MADV_DONTNEED) not releasing memory.

The result of calling this for a given range is that the OS can free the underlying pages. There will be less pages commited to the respective process. To me this boils down to releasing memory. ;-)

The mappings in the respective process will remain (albeit pointing to a COW zero page). If my process puts new data in a given range, the kernel will have to provide some pages backing this (commiting memory to me).

Comment: Well if the page mappings still exist, then the process virtual memory they represent has not been truly released, has it!  The process has not given the pages back permanently from its address space, so it has not "released" them.  At best it has told the kernel that its RSS can be reduced, but it has not actually reduced its VSZIZE, so it has not actually "released" any pages.  The key to understanding what "release" means in terms of heap and `malloc()` is in knowing that it means "it will reduce VSIZE" when it says it will "release free memory located at ... the top of the heap".