# When malloc_trim is (was) called automatically from free in glibc's ptmalloc or dlmalloc?

Tags: malloc, heap-memory, glibc

There is [incorrectly documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612438/can-malloc-trim-release-memory-from-the-middle-of-the-heap/42273711) function `malloc_trim` in glibc malloc (ptmalloc2), added in 1995 by Doug Lea and Wolfram Gloger (dlmalloc 2.5.4).

In glibc this function can return some memory freed by application back to operating system using negative sbrk for heap trimming, `madvise(...MADV_DONTNEED)` for unused pages in the middle of the heaps (this [feature is in `malloc_trim` since 2007 - glibc 2.9](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=68631c8eb92ff38d9da1ae34f6aa048539b199cc), but not in `systrim`), and probably not by trimming additional thread arenas (which are not sbrk-allocated by mmaped as separate heaps).

Such function can be very useful for some long-running C++ daemons, doing a lot of threads with very high number of mixed size allocations, both tiny, small, middle and large in required size. These daemons may have almost constant amount of live (allocated by malloc and not yet freed) memory, but at the same time grow in RSS (physical memory consumption) over time. But not every daemon can call this function, and not every author of such daemons know that he should call this function periodically.

Man page of `malloc_trim`  by Kerrisk http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html (2012) says in Notes about automatic calls to `malloc_trim` from other parts of glibc malloc:

> This function is automatically called by free(3) in certain circumstances.

(Also in http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/6390/print Advanced Memory Allocation, 2003 - *Automatic trimming is done inside the free() function by calling `memory_trim()`*)

This note is probably from source code of malloc/malloc.c which mentions in several places that `malloc_trim` is called automatically, probably from the `free()`:

```
 736  M_TRIM_THRESHOLD is the maximum amount of unused top-most memory
 737  to keep before releasing **via malloc_trim in free().**

 809  * When malloc_trim is called automatically from free(),
 810    it is used as the `pad' argument.

2722   systrim ... is also called by the public malloc_trim routine.
```

But according to grep for `malloc_trim` in glibc's malloc: http://code.metager.de/source/search?q=malloc_trim&path=%2Fgnu%2Fglibc%2Fmalloc%2F&project=gnu there are: declaration, definition and two calls of it from `tst-trim1.c` (test, not part of malloc). Same result for whole glibc grep (additionally it was listed in abilists). Actual implementation of `malloc_trim` is `mtrim()` but it is called only from `__malloc_trim()` of malloc.c.

So the question is: When `malloc_trim` or its internal implementation (`mtrim`/`mTRIm`) is called by glibc, is it called from `free` or `malloc` or `malloc_consolidate`, or any other function?

If this call is lost in current version of glibc, was it there in any earlier version of glibc, in any version of ptmalloc2, or in original dlmalloc code (http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html)? When and why it was removed? (What is the difference between `systrim`/`sys_trim` and `malloc_trim`?)

Comment: dlmalloc versions: http://g.oswego.edu/pub/misc/; glibc git https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c; version of malloc in glibc with `main_trim`: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/7aa6d2082273c05f52f18135f7ab66186f76dc44/malloc/malloc.c. Example of RSS memory grow: http://bugs.python.org/issue11849 - message 133929

Comment: A very good question. I find this method to test malloc_trim() on running apps: http://notes.secretsauce.net/notes/2016/04/08_glibc-malloc-inefficiency.html

Comment: It loos like it only runs automatically when freeing a large space: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/e182654151a0f6ebbe628c8f2f6b041c69adbac1/malloc/malloc.c#L4437. Unfortunately the threshold for "large" is not a tunable.